# Correct way to work with overloading methods in Java

Tags: java, methods, overloading

Suppose I have two methods

```
public void methodA(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e){
  //Some logic
  anotherMethodA(a, b, c, d, e);
}

public void methodA(int a, int b, int c){
  //Exactly the same logic but with only three parameters
  anotherMethodA(a, b, c);
}

//anotherMethodA and anotherMethodA also have the same logic but applied to a different number of parameters.
```

When the logic becomes a little bit more complex it looks like a lot of duplicate code.

Is there someway to write this in another way?

EDIT: What if the parameter types are different? (a, b, c, d and e are not all integers )

Comment: Why do you need overloading here? Just call the respective methods directly.

Comment: If you are using, `d, e` you can't have the exact same logic. Can you post how you are using d, e in your code.

Comment: what do anotherMethodA and anotherMethodB look like?

Comment: Maybe you should have a single anotherMethod taking an array of integers as argument. Hard to say without knowing anything about what it does and what a, b, c, d and e are.

Comment: Use Parameter Objects and have your logic stored into the same method

Comment: Changed my question to make it more clear. Of course methodA and methodB have the same name, otherwise it is not overloading. anotherMethodA performs some logic om parameters a, b, c, d and e. anotherMethodB performs exactly the same logic but only on a, b and c.

Comment: If you're doing some logic on a, b, c, d and e, you cannot possibly be performing the same logic on a, b and c, because that same logic will be missing d and e.

Comment: Suppose the logic is simply adding the elements to a list. ( It is not ). Then we can apply that logic to a, b, c, d and e. AND to a, b and c.

Comment: @AyoubRossi absolutely not. One did `a+b+c+d+e` and the other did `a+b+c`. That's flat-out not the same logic. Admittedly for a human it looks like there is some kind of similarity. Inaccurately. Silly humans.

Answer (score 3):

Another tool that you have at your disposal is the variable number of arguments using `...`. Depending on what is your logic you can use any of these methods. Overdoing it will run you into trouble.

Comment: I tried to be general when asking my question but in my specific case they are not all integers. Otherwise vararg would indeed work.

Comment: The problem is hard to understand when you say "It is same logic but applied to different number of parameters". You have to give an example of the logic and then we can suggest a solution.